# reason for hazelcast exceptions

Tags: java, hazelcast

I am running hazelcast server and getting the following exceptions (config copied below as well) - I would like to understand what is causing these issues i.e. 
**Migration initiator is not master node!**

**config**

```
 <group>
            <name>dev</name>  
            <password>dev-pass</password>  
        </group>
        <management-center enabled="false">http://localhost:8080/mancenter</management-center>
        <network>
            <port auto-increment="true" port-count="100">5701</port>
            <outbound-ports>
                <!--
                Allowed port range when connecting to other nodes.
                0 or * means use system provided port.
                -->
                <ports>0</ports>
            </outbound-ports>
            <join>
                <multicast enabled="false">
                    <multicast-group>224.2.2.3</multicast-group> 
                    <multicast-port>54327</multicast-port>
                </multicast>
                <tcp-ip enabled="true">
                    <interface>127.0.0.1</interface> 
                </tcp-ip>
                <aws enabled="false">
                    <access-key>my-access-key</access-key>
                    <secret-key>my-secret-key</secret-key>
                    <!--optional, default is us-east-1 -->
                    <region>us-west-1</region>
                    <!--optional, default is ec2.amazonaws.com. If set, region shouldn't be set as it will override this property -->
                    <host-header>ec2.amazonaws.com</host-header>
                    <!-- optional, only instances belonging to this group will be discovered, default will try all running instances -->
                    <security-group-name>hazelcast-sg</security-group-name>
                    <tag-key>type</tag-key>
                    <tag-value>hz-nodes</tag-value>
                </aws>
            </join>
            <interfaces enabled="false">
                <interface>10.10.1.*</interface>
            </interfaces>
            <ssl enabled="false" />
            <socket-interceptor enabled="false" />
            <symmetric-encryption enabled="false">
                <!--
                   encryption algorithm such as
                   DES/ECB/PKCS5Padding,
                   PBEWithMD5AndDES,
                   AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding,
                   Blowfish,
                   DESede
                -->
                <algorithm>PBEWithMD5AndDES</algorithm>
                <!-- salt value to use when generating the secret key -->
                <salt>fakesalt</salt>
                <!-- pass phrase to use when generating the secret key -->
                <password>fakepass</password>
                <!-- iteration count to use when generating the secret key -->
                <iteration-count>19</iteration-count>
            </symmetric-encryption>
        </network>
        <partition-group enabled="false"/>
```

**log statement**

```
   2014-09-05 05:56:21,481 WARN c.h.s.i.BasicInvocation [hz._hzInstance_1_dev.response] [127.0.0.1]:5701 [dev] [3.2.4] Retrying invocation: BasicInvocation{ serviceName='hz:core:partitionService', op=com.hazelcast.partition.impl.MigrationOperation{partitionId=0, migration=MigrationInfo{ partitionId=0, source=Address[127.0.0.1]:5701, destination=Address[127.0.0.1]:5703, master=Address[127.0.0.1]:5701, valid=true, processing=false}, compressed=true}, partitionId=0, replicaIndex=0, tryCount=250, tryPauseMillis=1000, invokeCount=130, callTimeout=60000, target=Address[127.0.0.1]:5703}, Reason: com.hazelcast.spi.exception.RetryableHazelcastException: Migration initiator is not master node! => com.hazelcast.partition.impl.MigrationOperation{partitionId=0, migration=MigrationInfo{ partitionId=0, source=Address[127.0.0.1]:5701, destination=Address[127.0.0.1]:5703, master=Address[127.0.0.1]:5701, valid=true, processing=false}, compressed=true}
    2014-09-05 05:56:31,489 WARN c.h.s.i.BasicInvocation [hz._hzInstance_1_dev.response] [127.0.0.1]:5701 [dev] [3.2.4] Retrying invocation: BasicInvocation{ serviceName='hz:core:partitionService', op=com.hazelcast.partition.impl.MigrationOperation{partitionId=0, migration=MigrationInfo{ partitionId=0, source=Address[127.0.0.1]:5701, destination=Address[127.0.0.1]:5703, master=Address[127.0.0.1]:5701, valid=true, processing=false}, compressed=true}, partitionId=0, replicaIndex=0, tryCount=250, tryPauseMillis=1000, invokeCount=140, callTimeout=60000, target=Address[127.0.0.1]:5703}, Reason: com.hazelcast.spi.exception.RetryableHazelcastException: Migration initiator is not master node! => com.hazelcast.partition.impl.MigrationOperation{partitionId=0, migration=MigrationInfo{ partitionId=0, source=Address[127.0.0.1]:5701, destination=Address[127.0.0.1]:5703, master=Address[127.0.0.1]:5701, valid=true, processing=false}, compressed=true}
    2014-09-05 05:56:41,497 WARN c.h.s.i.BasicInvocation [hz._hzInstance_1_dev.response] [127.0.0.1]:5701 [dev] [3.2.4] Retrying invocation: BasicInvocation{ serviceName='hz:core:partitionService', op=com.hazelcast.partition.impl.MigrationOperation{partitionId=0, migration=MigrationInfo{ partitionId=0, source=Address[127.0.0.1]:5701, destination=Address[127.0.0.1]:5703, master=Address[127.0.0.1]:5701, valid=true, processing=false}, compressed=true}, partitionId=0, replicaIndex=0, tryCount=250, tryPauseMillis=1000, invokeCount=150, callTimeout=60000, target=Address[127.0.0.1]:5703}, Reason: com.hazelcast.spi.exception.RetryableHazelcastException: Migration initiator is not master node! => com.hazelcast.partition.impl.MigrationOperation{partitionId=0, migration=MigrationInfo{ partitionId=0, source=Address[127.0.0.1]:5701, destination=Address[127.0.0.1]:5703, master=Address[127.0.0.1]:5701, valid=true, processing=false}, compressed=true}
    2014-09-05 05:56:49,029 WARN c.h.s.i.BasicInvocation [hz._hzInstance_1_dev.response] [127.0.0.1]:5701 [dev] [3.2.4] Retrying invocation: BasicInvocation{ serviceName='hz:impl:mapService', op=MergeOperation{wmAlertLogMap}, partitionId=256, replicaIndex=0, tryCount=250, tryPauseMillis=500, invokeCount=100, callTimeout=60000, target=Address[127.0.0.1]:5716}, Reason: com.hazelcast.spi.exception.RetryableHazelcastException: Map is not ready!!!
```

Comment: need to fix the log statement - the exception got truncated somehow

Comment: is your client connecting too soon right after the server connects and are you using eager load fror your map (map loader implementations)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like either your process does not have enough memory assigned to it or you have a mapstore implementation that has not completely run its course.  Try increasing memory (or number of nodes), make sure that the server comes up and listens on a port and perhaps monitor your java process memory usage with jvisualvm.